# Passing an entity into private methods for updating from request DTO

Tags: java

My Spring Boot application implements a `Service` class which is passed a request object from a `RestController`. This service method is responsible for updating an entity.

As there are a lot of fields to be updated, I separated the updating logic into several private methods for better readability like this:

```java
@Transactional
public void updateUser(UserRequest userRequest) {}
    final User user = userRepository.findById(userRequest.getId).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException()));
    updateUserFromRequest(user, userRequest);
}

private void updateUserFromRequest(User user, UserRequest userRequest) {
    updateUserMainData(user, userRequest);    
    updateUserAdditionalData(user, userRequest);
}

private void updateUserMainData(User user, UserRequest userRequest) {
  user.setProperty1(userRequest.getProperty1());
  user.setProperty2(userRequest.getProperty2());
  user.setProperty3(userRequest.getProperty3());
}

private void updateUserAdditionalData(User user, UserRequest userRequest) {
  user.setProperty4(userRequest.getProperty4());
  user.setProperty5(userRequest.getProperty5());
  user.setProperty6(userRequest.getProperty6());
}
```

While this works just fine, it feels "awkward" to pass around the `User` object into private methods. Is this apporach considered "good practice" or are there any other patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility could be hiding this complexity in the `User` class itself by adding an `update(UserRequest userRequest)` method. No more `User` being passed around into private methods (which could be considerer to have side effects).

If you don't want to add logic to your entity class, another possibility to make it less "awkward" would be to have all the `updateXXXX()` methods returning the updated `User`. Of course, this changes nothing in practical terms but it hints that the `User` was indeed updated in the method, reducing a little bit the "methods with side-effect" feeling.